# Internet Explorer bloqueia javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Programei um site e gostaria que funcionasse em todos os navegadores. Porém no IE, em todas as versões, ele não funciona como o desejado. Percebi que ele estava bloqueando meus códigos de javascript e jquery com uma mensagem sobre o activeX. 
 Onde eu trabalho, por exemplo, utilizamos um esqueleto padrão para o layout dos sites, o que facilita bastante. Deixo um link de um dos que fiz a seguir:
http://www.hoteldabarrars.com.br/
Ele roda normalmente o jquery e todos os scripts.
Agora no site que fiz sozinho do começo, o IE acaba bloquando com o ActiveX.

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Acrescentei informações no post da pergunta.

Comment: Em quais versão do IE você viu esse problema acontecendo?

Comment: Em todas as versões, levando em conta que testei primeiramente na última versão disponível. Acabei achando uma solução colocando o seguinte código antes da tag <html>:
 <!--saved from url=(0014)about:internet-->
Não entendi como ele funciona, mas funciona.

Comment: Poderia mostrar como seus scripts são referenciados no HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Realize os passo a seguir.

Configuração - Opões da Internet - Segurança - Nível personalizado - Controle ActiveX e plug-ins - Marque as flags que desejar.

A partir da tela que você acessar no caminho você tem que ir testando as configurações. Espero que de certo.

Comment: Mas não tem como fazer isso automaticamente? Tipo ele interpretar o jquery sem o usuário ter que entrar nas configurações do navegador?

Comment: A execução de um Script envolve questões de segurança e permissões. E se tratando de IE acho que não vai ser possível rodar automático. Mas aguarde, talvez alguém saiba como fazer. Marcando as flags você conseguiu executar? Até mais

Comment: @DiogoMalvezzi Bem vindo ao SOpt. Só para ajudar você entender a filosofia do site de Q&A, o importante são são perguntas e as respostas, de forma bem objetiva. Não somos iguais aos fóruns ou redes sociais. Damos respostas que podem ajudar qualquer pessoa que venha aqui ler. Por isso não nos referimos aos usuários, não damos boa noite (até porque pode ser dia quando a pessoa estiver lendo) e não nos cumprimentamos. Pelo menos é assim nas perguntas e respostas. Nos comentários somos mais livres.

Comment: Entendido @bigown